# complete compile sqlicipher for windows 10. how to import and use sqlcipher along with pycharm, my project, python

Tags: python, pycharm, pysqlcipher

i have downloaded sqlcipher-master file from github, and compile sqlicipher on windows 10

I run sqlite3.exe on command prompt

```
C:\Users\pcc\Desktop\sqlcipher-master\sqlcipher-master>sqlite3.exe
```

the result, it's working (hopefully).

```
SQLite version 3.42.0 2023-05-16 12:36:15 (SQLCipher 4.5.5 community)
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

now I am trying to use pysqlcipher or mysqlcipher on my python project in pycharm instead of cmd.

i have tried to install `pip3 install pysqlcipher3` this error occur

```
Failed to build pysqlcipher3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pysqlcipher3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

please help me complete the compile to include pycharm community 2021.3.2